# Problemas con JasperReport

Tags: java

Estoy utilizando el netbeans 8.2

Y este es el codigo que ocupo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y marca los siguientes errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las librerias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me ouede ayudar?

Comment: No se te puede ayudar, porque no incluyes el stacktrace del error completo, ni indicas la línea donde se lanza. Inclúyelo (***COMO TEXTO, NO COMO CAPTURA DE PANTALLA***) junto con el código relevante (***COMO TEXTO, NO COMO CAPTURA DE PANTALLA***) e igual así alguien tiene una idea de cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Viejo, yo tambien estoy usando JasperReport y tambien tenia ese error.

Primero si usas conexion a bd, abre tu conexion ahi:

```
JasperReport reporte = null;
//Cambias el String path por un URL Path
URL path = this.get().getResources("/nombreDeTuPaquete/NombreReporte.jasper);

try{
reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(path);
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, variableDeTuConexion);

JasperrViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint,false);
view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
view.setVisible(true);

}catch(JRException ex){}
```